# Cargo can't initialize index under Windows

Tags: windows, git, rust, rust-cargo

I have installed `rust` and `cargo` using `rustup` and I don't know why but somehow the `cargo` stopped working because it cannot initialize git index in hidden folder..

The problem is:

```bash
cargo run
> error: failed to get `reqwest` as a dependency of package `whatever 0.1.0 (C:\somewhere\in\windows\whatever)`
> 
> Caused by:
>   failed to initialize index git repository (in "C:\\somewhere\\in\\windows\\.cargo\\registry\\index\\github.com-some1hash")
> 
> Caused by:
>   failed to mark Git repository folder as hidden: ; class=0s (2)
```

---

It could be because our corp has decreased privileges of all users but **this means I can't compile anything on Windows**..

---

**edit:** The versions are `cargo 1.65.0` and `rustc 1.65.0` under `Windows 10 Enterprise`. All of the folders in path are created, but are empty as it fails on hiding the folder..

Comment: Is git available on the command line? I'd try going to a folder (maybe in C:\\somewhere\\in\\windows\\testfolder and see if u can do a git init to start with. 

Then possibly try to create a hidden folder? ... in case that error message is misleading

Comment: The git does work and even the hidden folder can be created.. This is what perplexes me.. Yet when I call the cargo again it doesn't care about the hidden folder and tries to create it again and unsurprisingly it fails again..